# Heat equation with discontinuous source

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity, heat-equation

I'm interested in solving a heat equation with a discontinuous source term in one dimension on the real line:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, t) = -x\theta(x) u(x, t) - x\theta(-x)u(-x, t) + D\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(x, t)$$

where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside function. The boundary conditions are that $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty} u(x, t) = 0$. The initial condition is arbitrary, but even for a symmetric Gaussian or a symmetric exponential an analytical solution would be interesting.

Because of the discontinuity in the right-hand side induced by $\theta(\cdot)$, my intuition would be to solve in the two domains $x > 0$ and $x < 0$ and patch them together at $x=0$. However, the source terms have the effect of causing exponential decay with rate $x$ at the point $x$ for $x > 0$ and corresponding growth at the point $-x$. This introduces an asymmetry, which should cause a diffusive flux back to the side $x > 0$. Solving for the solution in the two domains does not seem to capture this feedback, and I'm not sure how to solve globally. What are some avenues to proceed?

Comment: This is a diffusion-reaction equation. Moreover far away points are coupled together by the term with $u(-x,t)$.

Comment: Also, rhs is not discontinuous, thanks to the $x$ multiplication which drives source term to 0 at $x=0$.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: The $u(-x, t)$ term seems unnatural. On the negative $x$-axis, $u_t$ and $u_{xx}$ depend, through that term, directly on values on the positive axis, nonlocal behavior. Odd, but perhaps what you intend …

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your equation, it can be written as
$$
 u_t = -xu(|x|,t)+u_{xx}.
$$
Take first the case where $x>0$. A separation of variables
$u(x,t) = e^{-ct}X(x)$ gives
$$
 -c = -x+\frac{X''}{X}.
$$
A bounded solution to this uses the Airy function ${\rm Ai}$,
$$
 X(x) = {\rm Ai}(x-c),
$$
because ${\rm Ai}''(x) = x\,{\rm Ai}(x)$. Take $c$ to be minus a
negative root of ${\rm Ai}$; there are infinitely many choices.

So we have
$$
 u(x,t) = e^{-ct}{\rm Ai}(x-c), \qquad (x > 0).
$$

Then for $x<0$  we need to solve
$$
 u_t = -xe^{-ct}{\rm Ai}(-x-c)+u_{xx}.
$$
For this it is sufficient to take
$$
 u(x,t) = -e^{-ct}{\rm Ai}(-x-c), \qquad (x < 0).
$$
Thus $u$ is an odd function of $x$, and with the choice of $c$,
$u$ is continuous and once differentiable with respect to $x$ at $x = 0$.

To get existence of $u_{xx}(0,t)$, this can be achieved
by a linear combination of two such functions with different
values of $c$, arranged so that the second derivative is zero at the
origin.

Comment: I follow the algebra in this answer, but I am a bit confused by the conclusion. The equation itself suggests that the half $x > 0$ should decay with a rate $x$ (this will of course be modified by the diffusive term) and that that decay should be transported to the half $x < 0$. Your solution suggests there can be decay with any rate $c$. Moreover, what if the initial condition is symmetric? For example a symmetric exponential? I can solve the equation numerically and get something sensible in that case. In fact, the oscillatory side of the Airy function is nonphysical in this setting.

Comment: Take $f(x,t)$ to be the even part of $u(x,t)$ and $g(x,t)$ the odd part, but only for $x\ge 0$. Manipulating the equation I find that $f$ satisfies the heat equation $f_t = f_{xx}$ in $x>0$, and $g$ satisfies $g_t = -x(f+g)+g_{xx}$.  Perhaps this only helps in a theoretical sense that now you have a system of pde so some existence theorems apply.